# Get elements from list in python by ¿index?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to get the ids from this list to put them in an other to use

```
random.choice(list)
```

> [<Member id=986970159736586261 name='Nasgar-Bot' discriminator='5799'
> bot=True nick=None guild=>, <Member
> id=568157479020527636 name='ElmerKao' discriminator='0058' bot=False
> nick=None guild=>]

How can i get the id from here and put them into a list to use that command?

Comment: `x = random.choice(list)` / `print(x.id)`

Comment: Why are you getting a list? `random.choice()` only returns one element. Are you sure you didn't use `random.choices()`? It returns  a list.

Comment: There isn't enough information here for us to help you. I think you have a LoD and would like to build a list of IDs from that. We need to know what format the data is in, is it a string, dict, list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you worded you problem wasn't very clear but I think I understood, you want to add a user id in a list.Let's imagine the user sent a message. that you passed to your function with ctx.

```
ids = []
discord_id = ctx.message.author.id
ids.append(discord_id)
```

I am not sure if this answer is clear enough but try to give more context when asking a question.

PS: don't use list as a name for a list, it will break your code.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want to get the id from a list that I expect is a member, do list[0].id to get the first user's id. If you want to get the second user's id do list[1].id.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).